# Perl Excel OLE error opening different files from two scripts simultanesouly

Tags: perl, excel, ole, excel-2013

Trying to open and write data into two different excel files from separate perl scripts **but simultaneously**.

It doesn't throw any error if run one after other. But while running simultaneously it one of the script terminates with following error.

```
 entering 
 No Error 
 excel new created! 
 Win32::OLE(0.1709) error
 0x8001010a: "The message filter indicated that the application is
 busy"
   in METHOD/PROPERTYGET "Workbooks" at TwoExcelFiles.pl line 29. came out. sleeping 20 C:\Users\s.mailappan\Desktop\Test>
```

Perl script-1:

```
# ================
# Modules Required
# ================
use Win32::OLE qw(in with);                 # OLE Automation extensions
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';    # Extract constant definitions from TypeLib
use Cwd;                                    # Get pathname of current working directory
use File::Copy;                             # Copy files or filehandles

$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;

    # Open Excel application
    # my $Excel2 = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
     # || Win32::OLE->new( 'Excel.Application', 'Quit' );

    # use existing instance if Excel is already running

    printf "\nentering";
        eval {$Excel2 = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application');printf "\nNo Error";};
        die "Excel not installed" if $@;
        printf "\nexcel new created!";
        unless (defined $Excel2) {
        printf "\ncreating new excel on file-2";
            $Excel2 = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', sub {$_[0]->Quit;})
                    or die "Oops, cannot start Excel";
        }
        printf "\ncame out. sleeping 20";
    # Open workbook
    # my $Book1 = $Excel2->Workbooks->Open("C:\\Users\\s.mailappan\\Desktop\\Test\\CoreNetwork_Master_Excel_WSS_Oma.xlsx");
    my $Book2 = $Excel2->Workbooks->Open("C:\\Users\\s.mailappan\\Desktop\\Test\\CoreNetwork_Master_Excel_WSS_Che.xlsx");
    # $Book1->Save;
    # $Book1->Close();

    $Book2->Save;
    $Book2->Close();
    sleep(20);
    printf "\nsleep done";
    $Excel2->Quit();
```

Perl script-2:

```
# ================
# Modules Required
# ================
use Win32::OLE qw(in with);                 # OLE Automation extensions
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';    # Extract constant definitions from TypeLib
use Cwd;                                    # Get pathname of current working directory
use File::Copy;                             # Copy files or filehandles

$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;

    # Open Excel application
    # my $Excel1 = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
     # || Win32::OLE->new( 'Excel.Application', 'Quit' );

    # use existing instance if Excel is already running

    printf "\nentering";
        eval {$Excel1 = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application');printf "\nNo Error";};
        die "Excel not installed" if $@;
        printf "\nexcel new created!";
        unless (defined $Excel1) {
        printf "\ncreating new excel on file-2";
            $Excel1 = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', sub {$_[0]->Quit;})
                    or die "Oops, cannot start Excel";
        }
        printf "\ncame out. sleeping 20";
    # Open workbook
    my $Book1 = $Excel1->Workbooks->Open("C:\\Users\\s.mailappan\\Desktop\\Test\\CoreNetwork_Master_Excel_WSS_Oma.xlsx");
    # my $Book2 = $Excel1->Workbooks->Open("C:\\Users\\s.mailappan\\Desktop\\Test\\CoreNetwork_Master_Excel_WSS_Che.xlsx");
    $Book1->Save;
    $Book1->Close();

    # $Book2->Save;
    # $Book2->Close();
    sleep(20);
    printf "\nsleep done";
    $Excel1->Quit();
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the files in read only?

Comment: no. as i need to update the excel files.

Comment: well... then you can't open the same file in two different instances at the same time

Comment: I am trying to open two different excel files!! not the same.

Comment: oops... sorry, i didn't notice. have you tried with `Win32::OLE->new` instead of `Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject`?

Comment: Yes Stenci. Infact thats what i first tired and didnt work(commented out in my sample code). then i tried the GetActiveObject.

BTW, first of all, can we associate Excel OLE more than once to perl simultaneously. Is that possible?

Comment: I haven't done it in perl, but I do it often. I have one (or more) interactive Excel sessions, and one or two in background used by other applications, and they don't bother each other.

Comment: Thanks stenci. I was mistaken about using "Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject" instead of "Win32::OLE->new". Infact its works when using "Win32::OLE->new". Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted by stenci - instead of using Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject, using Win32::OLE->new works as defined below.

```
unless (defined $Excel1_Parse4G) {
  $Excel1_Parse4G = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', sub {$_[0]->Quit;})
  or die "Oops, cannot start Excel";
}   
my $Book1 = $Excel1_Parse4G->Workbooks->Open("C:\\path\file1.xls");

unless (defined $Excel2_Parse4G) {
  $Excel2_Parse4G = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', sub {$_[0]->Quit;})
  or die "Oops, cannot start Excel";
}   
my $Book2 = $Excel2_Parse4G->Workbooks->Open("C:\\path\file2.xls");
```