# Data inconsistency issue while writing data into different excel files simultaneously using Perl Excel OLE

Tags: perl, excel, ole, vba

With the following perl script, I'm trying to open and write data into different excel sheets at the same time.

Though it works, i see some data inconsistency issues with this approach.

i.e. some of the file1 data is seen in file2 and vicer-versa.

I don't have a clear understanding on Perl OLE handles. Since its the same perl OLE handle for different files, does perl sees all the different files as just one?

If its so how to avoid this scenario?

perl Parser.pl C:\report1.xlsx

perl Parser.pl C:\report2.xlsx

perl Parser.pl C:\report3.xlsx

## Parser.pl

```
use Win32::OLE qw(in with);                 # OLE Automation extensions
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';    # Extract constant definitions from TypeLib

unless (defined $Excel1) {
    $Excel1 = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', sub {$_[0]->Quit;})
    or die "Oops, cannot start Excel";
}

$ReportFile = $ARGV[0];

# Open workbook
my $Book1 = $Excel1->Workbooks->Open($ReportFile);
{
    #### WRTIE DATA INTO EXCEL ####
}

$Book1->Save;
$Book1->Close();
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is definitely in the OLE interface. You can try Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject instead of new, once you have an instance open. Note that if you do this then you probably want to have something to open the new excel and the close it after all of your script invocations are done.

Failing that you might consider using [Excel::Writer::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel%3a%3aWriter%3a%3aXLSX) or similar as an interface for building your spreadsheet. And this won't be dependent on Excel, or windows for that matter. If you are appending, altering spreadsheet files then you would need to bake something using [Spreadsheet::Read](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Spreadsheet%3a%3aRead) to get to the contents and then pass that data to your writer.

Using the alternate modules will be safer and more portable.

Comment: With Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject, i cant work on multiple excel files simultaneously. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115476/perl-excel-ole-error-opening-different-files-from-two-scripts-simultanesouly

Comment: Wasn't sure if there was going to be an isolation problem or not, but it appears there is. There is a problem with the COM threading model at the heart of this which I remember reading somewhere. Use the alternate module as suggested and you will be free of the problems. It will make your work re-usable should the current script be moved off running on one machine and out into the world.